# Ruby scraper. How to export to CSV?

Tags: ruby, fastercsv, scraper, anemone

I wrote this ruby script to scrape product info from the manufacturer website. The scraping and storage of the product objects in an array works, but I can't figure out how to export the array data to a csv file. This error is being thrown:
scraper.rb:45: undefined method `send_data' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

I do not understand this piece of code. What's this doing and why isn't it working right?

```
  send_data csv_data, 
            :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present', 
            :disposition => "attachment; filename=products.csv"
```

Full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'anemone'
require 'fastercsv'

productsArray = Array.new

class Product
    attr_accessor :name, :sku, :desc
end

# Scraper Code

Anemone.crawl("http://retail.pelicanbayltd.com/") do |anemone|
    anemone.on_every_page do |page|

        currentPage = Product.new

        #Product info parsing
        currentPage.name = page.doc.css(".page_headers").text
        currentPage.sku = page.doc.css("tr:nth-child(2) strong").text
        currentPage.desc = page.doc.css("tr:nth-child(4) .item").text

        if currentPage.sku =~ /#\d\d\d\d/
            currentPage.sku = currentPage.sku[1..-1]
            productsArray.push(currentPage)
        end
    end
end

# CSV Export Code

products = productsArray.find(:all) 
csv_data = FasterCSV.generate do |csv| 
    # header row 
    csv << ["sku", "name", "desc"] 

    # data rows 
    productsArray.each do |product| 
      csv << [product.sku, product.name, product.desc] 
    end 
  end 

  send_data csv_data, 
            :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present', 
            :disposition => "attachment; filename=products.csv"
```

Comment: Where did you see any reference to a `send_data` method? Why did you think that would work?  It looks like it came from something that's sending email?  You have your CSV data in `csv_data`; what do you want to do with it?  If you want it in a file, open a file and write to it.

Comment: @MarkReed: [`send_data`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data)

Comment: Ah, of course, I should have known - an ActionSomething method. Thank you, Rails, the double-edged sword of Ruby.

Comment: @MarkReed: I'd be the last person to have anything good to say about the Rails documentation but there is a search box at the top of http://api.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: @muistooshort: have no complaints about figuring out how to do stuff in Rails, once I know I'm using Rails. I love Rails.  The opposite edge of that sword is the sheer number of newbies confused into thinking that Rails == Ruby, and trying to use all those helpful methods outside of their framework home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File.open('filename.csv', 'w') do |f|
  f.write(csv_data)
end
```

Comment: I grabbed that from sample code. Thank you both for the help I got it working now. noob here

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Ruby, you should be using Ruby 1.9 or later, in which case you can use the built-in CSV output which builds in fast csv plus l18n support:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open('filename.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  csv << [sku, name, desc]
end
```

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Answer (score 0):

It probably makes more sense to do:

```
@csv = FasterCSV.open('filename.csv', 'w')
```

and then write to it as you go along:

```
@csv << [sku, name, desc]
```

that way if your script crashes halfway through you've at least got half of the data.